# PostgreSQL and Django Query for report not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using Python Django and PostgreSQL to build our report app.

I am using below mention query to find some details. the query mention below is running fine in PostgreSQL command line and giving result in 2 sc for 2 million cards but when i i am try the same in Django application it is taking too much of time and the web page is expired while running this query.

can anyone help how to make query faster in Django? Or help me in correcting this query to be used in Django

**rows = M_Assign.objects.raw(''' select C.id,M."merchant_name",C."MERCHANT_ID",S."store_id" Owning_Store_ID ,S."store_name" Owning_Store_Name,F."franchisee_name" Owning_Group,C."ACCOUNT_NUMBER",C."STORE_ID",C."GIFT_LIST_REF" FROM vdaccount_card_assign C INNER JOIN vd_merchant_master M ON C."MERCHANT_ID"=M."merchant_id" AND C."MERCHANT_ID"='003561002966107' INNER JOIN vd_store_master S ON S."store_id"=C."GIFT_LIST_REF" OR C."GIFT_LIST_REF"='' INNER JOIN vd_franchisee F ON S."franchisee_id"=F."franchisee_id" ''')**

Regards
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Sending 2 million rows across a network (presumably) and reading them into a client is going to take some time.  Is there any reason to think that this is not the only issue involved?  If your test from the command-line was with "EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)", that can be much faster as the server just throws away the data as soon as it obtains it.  It doesn't need to either format the data into "wire" format, or send the formatted data anywhere, both of which can be slow.

If you think the problem is with the actual execution, you will have to show us the plans for both cases.  You can use [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) with log_analyze set to record the plan as executed from Django, and then fetch it from the log files.